# How can i translate my camera node position after rotation in required direction in SceneKit?

Tags: swift, ios9, scenekit

I am developing a 3D application using SceneKit in iOS, I need to translate my camera position after rotation. Can anybody help me to do this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do this by stringing together a few SCNMatrix4 operations.

```
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()

//start off with an identity matrix
var cameraTransform = SCMMatrix4Identity

//rotate by 90degrees about Z axis
cameraTransform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(cameraTransform, Float(M_PI_2), 0, 0, 1)

//translate by 2 units in x direction
cameraTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(cameraTransform, 2, 0, 0)

//set the camera's transform
cameraNode.transform = cameraTransform
```

Comment: thanks it is working fine but i need to translate the camera in the direction where camera is looking after rotation. Means every time when i rotate camera using touch move then target position will be changed, So i want to translate in that position.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!